# Create values for each time the for loop loops

Tags: java, for-loop

So I'm trying to create a for loops that creates a new value each times it runs.
Something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < con.length; i++) {
    Vector max[i] = new Vector(i+1, i+2, i+3);
}
```

I'm kind of new to java, so i don't understand it very well.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
Vector[] max = new Vector[con.length];

for(int i = 0; i < con.length; i++) {
    max[i] = new Vector(i+1, i+2, i+3);
}
```