# Could not pass event PlayerMoveEvent to FactionPlay error in Java code

Tags: java, for-loop

Earlier I posted [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930678/create-values-for-each-time-the-for-loop-loops) asking for how to make multiple values out of a for loop.
After a while I ran into a problem, which I don't know how to fix nor know why it happened.
This is the code that I have:

```
for(int x = 0; x < con.length; x++) 
{
    maxS[x] = main.getConfig().getString("areas." + con[x] + ".max").split(", ").toString();
    minS[x] = main.getConfig().getString("areas." + con[x] + ".min").split(", ").toString();
    event.getPlayer().sendMessage("1");
    for(int y = 0; y < maxS.length; y++) 
    {
        maxV[y] = new Vector(Integer.parseInt(maxS[y]), Integer.parseInt(maxS[y+1]), Integer.parseInt(maxS[y+2]));
        minV[y] = new Vector(Integer.parseInt(minS[y]), Integer.parseInt(minS[y+1]), Integer.parseInt(minS[y+2]));

        event.getPlayer().sendMessage("2");
    }
}
```

The error message:

> 2013-07-29 20:32:12 [SEVERE] Could not pass event PlayerMoveEvent to FactionPlay v1.6.2 org.bukkit.event.EventException
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:427)
> at org.bukkit.plugin.RegisteredListener.callEvent(RegisteredListener.java:62)
> at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.fireEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:477)
> at org.bukkit.plugin.SimplePluginManager.callEvent(SimplePluginManager.java:462)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.PlayerConnection.a(PlayerConnection.java:227)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.Packet10Flying.handle(SourceFile:136)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.NetworkManager.b(NetworkManager.java:296)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.PlayerConnection.e(PlayerConnection.java:116)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.ServerConnection.b(SourceFile:37)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServerConnection.b(SourceFile:30)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.t(MinecraftServer.java:590)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.DedicatedServer.t(DedicatedServer.java:226)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.s(MinecraftServer.java:486)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.MinecraftServer.run(MinecraftServer.java:419)
> at net.minecraft.server.v1_6_R2.ThreadServerApplication.run(SourceFile:582)
> Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "    [Ljava.lang.String;@af7327"
> at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
> at me.BlueJelly.FactionPlay_SP.PlayerListener.onPlayerMove(PlayerListener.java:191)
> at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor89.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> at org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPluginLoader$1.execute(JavaPluginLoader.java:425)
> ... 14 more

Comment: What is the problem you ran into?

Comment: Can you show us the error?

Comment: Without the error message, none of us can help you.

Comment: I'm _guessing_ that he's getting an IndexOutOfRangeException. `y` goes until maxS.length, but he references maxS[y+2]. But we definitely need/want more information!

Comment: @ChrisForrence that or he didn't initialize it in the first place.

Comment: what is `maxV` and `minV`?

Comment: It's a NumberFormatException, so there must be some parsing going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging by your error message, it looks like your calls to `Integer.parseInt` aren't actually getting a string that can be parsed to an int.

Instead they're getting the string `"    [Ljava.lang.String;@af7327"`.

You should re-evaluate how you're getting those strings

---

The following line looks wrong.

```
maxS[x] = main.getConfig().getString("areas." + con[x] + ".max").split(", ").toString();
```

This might just be my c# experience talking, but I normally expect a `.split()` call to return an array of `string` rather than a single `string`.

It's hard to tell without looking at the rest of your code, but I'd expect to see a line that looks more like the following

```
maxS = main.getConfig().getString("areas." + con[x] + ".max").split(", ");
```